# Existential Quantifiers translated into categorical statements?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I've been recently trying to translate the [categorical statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_proposition) into the quantifiers ($\forall$ and $\exists$).

## Attempts

I believe I can make the E statement as $$\nexists s:p,$$the A statement as $$\neg\nexists s:p,$$ the I statement as $$\exists s:p,$$
and the O statement as $$\neg\exists s:p.$$

## Question

*Are my formulas correct?* If not, how might I translate the categorical statements correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I would do it in AEIO order:
$$\forall x:S(x)\implies P(x)$$
$$\forall x:S(x)\implies \neg P(x)$$
$$\exists x:S(x)\wedge P(x)$$
$$\exists x:S(x)\wedge \neg P(x)$$

Comment: For I and O: Why did you use the $\wedge$ operator? Why not the $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: $A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\vee B$. $A$ implies $B$ if and only if either $A$ is false or $B$ is true. The wedge operator means "and." There is an $x$ such that $S(x)$ and $P(x)$ (some $S$ are $P$). There is an $x$ such that $S(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$ (some $S$ are not $P$).

Comment: Thanks again! You did wonders!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien You're welcome.